# execsql 1.72 unable to install Python

Tags: python, ubuntu, encoding, pip, setup.py

**System / Version Information:**

- Windows Server 2019 Datacenter
- Ubuntu 16.04
- Python 2.7
- pip 20.1

I am attempting to install the latest version of execsql (1.72) using the command:

```
pip install execsql
```

When I run the code the following cell is the result.

```
> Collecting execsql                                                    
> Using cached execsql-1.72.2.tar.gz (115 kB)                           
> ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:                        
> command: /usr/bin/python -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize;
> sys.argv[0] = '"'"'/tmp/pip-install-UoDS2j/execsql/setup.py'"'"';
> __file__='"'"'/tmp/pip-install-UoDS2j/execsql/setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize,
> '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"',
> '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))'
> egg_info --egg-base /tmp/pip-pip-egg-info-LDfNrk                      
> cwd: /tmp/pip-install-UoDS2j/execsql/                                 
> Complete output (5 lines):                                            
> Traceback (most recent call last):                                    
> File "<string>", line 1, in <module>                                  
> File "/tmp/pip-install-UoDS2j/execsql/setup.py", line 3, in <module>  
> with open('README.md', encoding='utf-8') as f:                        
> TypeError: 'encoding' is an invalid keyword argument for this function
> ----------------------------------------                                                                            ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1: python setup.py
> egg_info Check the logs for full command output.
```

This is on a fresh instance of both Ubuntu and Python. I would greatly appreciate assistance with this issue as I am unable to find any documentation online that points me in the right direction. The following list covers steps that I have already taken in an attempt to resolve the issue:

- `pip install -U setuptools`
- `pip install --upgrade setuptools wheel`
- `pip install python-language-server`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error

> with open('README.md', encoding='utf-8') as f:
>   TypeError: 'encoding' is an invalid keyword argument for this function

occurs because the code is not compatible with Python 2.  The most recent version of `execsql` that I could install under without this error was 1.47.0.

Comment: Thank you so much for your quick reply. I figured it was something simple like that. Version 1.47 installed successfully for me.